# get information from two different mysql tables with different result

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I've searched a lot but didn't find anything. My question is a bit hard to understand.

I have two tables one has "review" info and other has "restaurant" info.
Table name called "reviews" which has 'restaurantID' column , stored the same integer values that have other table "restaurant" have.

```
table name = reviews                    table name - restaurant
____________________________            _______________________
restaurantID - rating- review           restaurantID -name-location
```

i want to use the same html search form and when i'll search with "rating". it will give me information of "restaurant name","location" and "rating". 
and vice versa. ratings are from 1 to 5.

I've tried different queries in mysql workbench. but didn't find any luck.
any help would be appreciate. i am using php PDO.
PS- please let me know if you didn't understood the question, it's bit of an essay . Cheers

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i've tried using JOIN,INNER JOIN,and UNION but they didn't work . search only shows "restaurant" info.

Comment: When we say `Show` we mean Post your query. Then we can provide much better assistance in finding the solution.

Comment: Also, can a restaurant have many reviews? Most likely, so you may want to account for that in your query.

Comment: yes , restaurant can have multiple reviews .

Comment: SELECT reviews.*, restaurant.* From reviews INNER JOIN restaurant ON reviews.restaurantID = ..restaurant.restaurantID

Comment: See the answer by @lloiacono below as well as my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can joins the two tables using the restaurantID column:

```
SELECT resto.name, resto.location, rev.rating
FROM restaurant as resto
LEFT JOIN review as rev
ON rev.restaurantID = resto.restaurantID
WHERE
resto.name = 'SOME_RESTAURANT_NAME';
```

Comment: So, knowing now that a restaurant may have multiple reviews, you may want `Max(rev.rating)` and `Group By` in this query. That should give them something they can use.

Comment: when i tried to run it, it only worked with ratings unfortunately. is it possible that if i search with restaurant that has no review or rating so i can get only those results?

Comment: Change the `Join` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: LEFT JOIN did the thing. thank you so much @WEI_DBA .